# Return type of iterator() method in java

Tags: java, methods, collections, iterator, return-type

I am a new-comer in Java and in process of learning.
I need a an answer of following question supported with valid theory.
Consider the following line-

```
Iterator itr = al.iterator();
```

where *al* is some collection object of ArrayList (class) type.
I want to know what is here the return type of

#### al.iterator()

It is not definitely of a primitive data type, then it could be an **object** , but since every object belong to a class then it is of **which class**. Documentation and books etc says it has return type of Iterator. But *Iterator* is an interface. On other hand we say an interface could not have a direct object. Although interface variable could refer to an object of a class or classes that implements it.

#### -

So the above syntax is correct (as Iterator variable *itr* could be used to refer to an object of some class implementing it). But in realty it is object of which class?  And can substituting *itr* with reference variable of that class will cause no error (I have tried substituting *itr* with ref. variable of ArrayList class in above line but that causes an error). I am using this syntax very often also in Generics form, but dont know the theory behind this. And I am supposing I am lacking a very basic concept here. Please rectify.

Comment: [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#iterator()) the javadoc.

Comment: concept is [programming to an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992384/program-to-an-interface-what-does-it-mean) @SotiriosDelimanolis i remember when we had the same reputation xD

Comment: @nachokk I have an addictive personality. I spend too much time here.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to know what is here the return type of al.iterator()

**You shouldn't care**. It doesn't matter what particular implementation of Iterator the method returns, only that it returns an Iterator. You can call next, hasNext, and remove, or iterate with a for-each loop, without knowing that it happens to be an ArrayList.Itr or whatever the implementation is.

Suppose the Java developers working on the ArrayList want to rename their iterator implementation to ArrayListIterator instead of whatever they're calling it now. If your code relied on knowing the exact Iterator implementation, you would have to change your code just to handle an ArrayList-internal change you shouldn't even see.

Comment: If I have **shouldn't care** , I would have never asked this question here. Or you **shouldn't care** to give this answer. Anyway this is not answer of my question.

Comment: @user3528086: You will find that not caring is a surprisingly important programming skill. If your code cares too much about what goes on behind the abstraction barriers of other code, it will be extremely fragile and unmaintainable.

Comment: Hi @user2357112 **not caring** is definitely a virtue; can help you practically in many situations. I have this virtue in me. But I let this virtue down when I am asking this question. Caring on the other hand is also definitely equal virtue!

Answer (score 2):

You are right saying that `Iterator` is an interface. So, some class must implement this interface so you can use it.

The iterator interface defines what an iterator should do. In this case, the class ArrayList provides its own implementation of this interface.

**What you get from `al.iterator()`** is the inner class of ArrayList **Itr** (see following code, which IS iterator. (as we kind of describe the IS-A relationship)

(you can think of an inner class as a normal class for now. So the answer to your question is **Itr**, which is just a name, and all you should care about is its function, which is defined by interface Iterator.)

```
   /**
     * An optimized version of AbstractList.Itr
     */
    private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
        int cursor;       // index of next element to return
        int lastRet = -1; // index of last element returned; -1 if no such
        int expectedModCount = modCount;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return cursor != size;
        }
       .....
  }
```

This code is by Josh Bloch and Neal Gafter, who wrote the ArrayList class.

Comment: Hi @Weishi Zeng that is very near to my answer. The object of _Itr_ the inner class of ArrayList, could be the return-type of _iterator ()_ method. But then can we use variable of _Itr_ inner class inplace of _Iterator_ interface variable (in the syntax line of above question) (Initiating variable of _Itr_ class like- 'ArrayList.Itr itr = new ArrayList.Itr ();' causes error, since _Itr_ class is private)

Answer (score 1):

The implementation is defined in `AbstractList` itself. Find it at its [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractList.java).

```
public abstract class AbstractList<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> implements List<E> {
    private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
       ...
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
       return new Itr();
    }
}
```

Try

```
System.out.println(new ArrayList<String>().iterator().getClass().getName());
```

output

```
java.util.AbstractList$Itr
```

Comment: The source code seems to indicate that ArrayList has its own Itr inner class; it doesn't use the AbstractList implementation.

Comment: Look at again on `iterator()` method that is part of `AbstractList` class.

Comment: I didn't find any inner class `Itr` in `ArrayList`. Did you find it?

Comment: It's right here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.Itr

Comment: Try it in eclipse. Its not clear from here it says : `An optimized version of AbstractList.Itr`

Comment: When I try your code, I get `java.util.ArrayList$Itr`.

Comment: I am using Java 
6. may be its improved version in Java 7

Comment: I'm still on Java 6 too. (We really should both be on Java 8 now. Dunno what they're doing in that version, but I doubt they changed it.)

Comment: I am using `jdk1.6.0_23`. No matter what is the implantation. I think you have got the answer of your question `every object belong to a class then it is of which class?`

Comment: And now you have a way to know the actual class name. :)

Comment: Hi @Braj What you say is correct. The _iterator()_ method could be defined in inner class of AbstractList. But it is not always a method defined in class or inner class have return type of that class. Question is not where it is defined. **Question** is that it have return type of what (or return-type of object of which class).

Comment: I think you haven't looked at type parameter `Iterator<E>`. Its the same type that you used while creating an `ArrayList<E>` (AbstractList<E> ).

Answer (score 1):

You can define the return type of your Iterator beforehand. As you declare the iterator, you can (and should) define the type of your list items like this:

`Iterator<File> itr = al.iterator();`

So when you access `itr` you don't have to cast to file, e.g. `(File) itr.next()` but can directly use it in your while loop:

`while (it.hasNext()) { File f = itr.next() }`

Your compiler now won't complain when using next().

Answer (score 0):

Iterator is generic and doesn't return a specific type unless you define it in the ArrayList. Iterator is an interface (part of the Java Collections) that returns the  type that was passed to it. The Iterator is used to traverse the list of elements, and remove an element if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Simply it returns the object it does iterate. For example you can refer to the code below.

```
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        String str = itr.next().toString(); // Converting an answer type object into String.
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```