# Can we achieve polymorphism with variable in java?

Tags: java, polymorphism

During an interview i have been asked about polymorphism. Then the interviewer asked "Can we achieve polymorphism with variable in java ?".

I tried many sources but unable to find anysuitable answer.

Plz help me guys......

Comment: This is completely unclear, but maybe...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992384/program-to-an-interface-what-does-it-mean

Comment: Assuming "Can we achieve polymorphism with variable in java ?" is a direct quote, that interviewer needs a serious lesson in expressiveness.

Comment: no we can not. we can override methods but not variables

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to the question **NO**, the variables are not polymorphic in Java ie, they do not override one another. You can simply undertsand this that the variables are resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Anything which is resolved at complile time,**runtime polymorphism** cannot be achieved using that. In java,all the methods are virtual by default,hence java exhibits Runtime Polymorphism by default regarding the methods. The question asked to you had a straightforward answer that "No,polymorphism cannot be achieved using variables in java as they are mapped at compile time"