# What's the difference between these ways of initializing a HashMap?

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

I used a HashMap for my program and it works fine, but I don't understand the difference between these initializations of HashMap.

Let's say I'm implementing a HashMap with a character as a key and an integer as a value. What's the difference between these?

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> alphabet1 = new HashMap();
HashMap<Character, Integer> alphabet1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
HashMap alphabet1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
Map alphabet1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
HashMap alphabet1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
HashMap alphabet1 = new HashMap();
Map alphabet1 = new HashMap();
```

Comment: Get through from generics http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/ you will automatically get understand all these.

Comment: All those choices, and it still doesn't include the one that I'd typically use: `Map<Character, Integer> alphabet1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();`. [I'm still using Java 5]

Comment: And as of Java 7 (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) you can write: `Map<Character, Integer> alphabet1 = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anything involving `HashMap` or `Map` without a type argument (the angle brackets < and > and the part between them) is a [raw type and shouldn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). A raw type is not generic and lets you do unsafe things.

The "correct" ways are

```
Map<Character, Integer> alphabet1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
HashMap<Character, Integer> alphabet1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
```

The first uses the interface Map as the reference type. [It is generally more idiomatic and a good style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992384/program-to-an-interface-what-does-it-mean).

Also another way you did not mention, [using the Java 7 diamond operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7)

```
Map<Character, Integer> alphabet1 = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<Character, Integer> alphabet1 = new HashMap<>();
```

Which is more or less equivalent to the first two correct ways. The arguments to the reference type on the left-hand side are supplied implicitly to the constructor on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 3):

You missed the right choice:

```
Map<Character, Integer> alphabet1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
```

1. Generics declaration allows compiler to check your 'alphabet1' usages during compile-time.
2. Map/HashMap on left side declares how your 'alphabet1' variable should be considered: either as Map (interface) or HashMap (instance of concrete class). Of course interface is preferred - it makes your code more robust to further changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> alphabet1 = new HashMap(); // (1)
```

(1) initializes a `HashMap` without using generics but uses an unsafe cast to a `HashMap` with generics afterwards. This should raise a compiler warning.

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> alphabet1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(); // (2)
```

(2) Initializes a `HashMap` with generics and declares a variable of the type `HashMap` with generics. It can be shorthanded to

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> alphabet1 = new HashMap<>(); // (2b)
```

Here, the compiler uses type inference to infer the genrics of the `HashMap` from the declaration of the left hand side.

```
HashMap alphabet1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(); // (3)
```

(3) Initialzes a HashMap with generics, but the variable `alphabet1` does not reuse the generics information. Thus, you can not access the methods on this `HashMap` value in a generic manner (e.g., you will get a value cast to an `java.lang.Object` when calling `alphabet1.get('a')` and not cast to an `Integer`).

```
Map alphabet1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(); // (4)
```

(4) is similar to (3) but here, the `alphabet1` is typed with `Map` instead of `HashMap`. Thus, you cannot access methods being defined in `HashMap` but not in its super interface `Map`.

```
HashMap alphabet1 = new HashMap(); // (5)
```

(5) is similar to (3), it does not use generics for initializing the `HashMap`.

```
Map alphabet1 = new HashMap(); // (6)
```

(6) is similar to (4) and does not use generics for initializing the `HashMap`.

Comment: 1 and 2 are **not** the same; 1 is missing the empty `<>`.