# Dynamically implementing interface?

Tags: java, oop, selenium-webdriver

I was thinking on the following example for taking a screenshot in WebDriver2:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

When a class implements an Interface, the class must implement the defined the methods in the interface, right?

So, how come during runtime we implement `TakeScreenshot` interface, without implementing the logic in `getScreenshotAs` method before that?

I tried to simulate it this way:

```
interface TakeScreenShot{ public void getScreenshotAs(); }

class WebDriver
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        WebDriver driver = new WebDriver();
        ((TakeScreenShot)driver).getScreenshot();
    }
}
```

I ran it in Ideone and I am getting a runtime error:

`Runtime error  time: 0.05 memory: 711168 signal:-1`

So, how does it work in WebDriver?

Comment: Because the class of `driver` already implements `TakesScreenshot`. Look at the actual type of `driver` in a debugger or sysout `driver.getClass().getName()` and lookup what that class actually implements.

Comment: @k5_ then why do we cast it to `TakeScreenShot`? Can't we just do `driver.getScreenshotAs()`?

Comment: It might just work, i'm not too familiar with the hierarchy of that class and you did not paste enough. But if it does not work without the cast (and works with) the type of `driver` field/variable does not implement that interface. Only the dynamic type does.

Comment: What is the *declared* type of your variable `driver`? Is it `WebDriver` ? Does that interface extend `TakesScreenshot` ?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt question updated.

Comment: @CuriousGuy so change the type of `driver` to `FirefoxDriver` and it will work without the cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, `WebDriver` is an interface - and interface that doesn't extend `TakesScreenshot`. So if you have a variable `driver` of the *declared* type `WebDriver`, you can't call methods on that variable that are in `TakesScreenshot`.

But the variable `driver` points to an actual object which has an implementation **class** - `FirefoxDriver`. And `FirefoxDriver` does implement the `TakesScreenshot` interface.

There are several other ways in which you can invoke the `getScreenshotAs` method:

Example 1:

> change the declared type of `driver` to `FirefoxDriver` which does
>   implement `TakesScreenshot`:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
File scrFile = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

Example 2:

> cast `WebDriver driver` to `FirefoxDriver` instead of
>   `TakesScreenshot` - because `FirefoxDriver` implements
>   `TakesScreenshot` you can call methods from the latter interface
>   directly through type `FirefoxDriver`.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
File scrFile = ((FirefoxDriver)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

Now in your second example, you have a **class** `WebDriver` (not an *interface*) and that class doesn't implement `TakesScreenshot` so you can't cast it to that type.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was just thinking. But I have another question - why don't I just create a `FirefoxDriver` and save all the effort of casting in such cases? Why all tutorials and examples are using `WebDriver` objects instead of the 'real' drivers?

Comment: @CuriousGuy that's because in most cases, you care about using the `WebDriver` methods down the line, in more complicated scenarios. Please don't let this example of theirs confuse you and give you a bad impression of programming to an interface. It's actually quite a useful technique in most cases, it's just that it's not useful in this simple case.

Comment: @CuriousGuy I guess the thinking behind it is that not all drivers may be capable of taking a screenshot. But it's cumbersome, and from the Javadoc it looks like all drivers do implement `TakesScreenshot`, so it may be something historical that doesn't make a lot of sense anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the interface `WebDriver` is not a subclass of `TakesScreenshot`. However, the object being assigned to driver in your first snippet is of type  `FirefoxDriver` which  is [both a WebDriver and TakesScreenshot.](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html)

The technique being done in your first snippet is "programming to an interface". There are a lot of duplicate questions regarding that, but [this answer is the simplest.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1992479/1593883)

You basically do that when you only care that `driver` is a `WebDriver` instance, and you don't care whether it is an OperaDriver, ChromeDriver, etc. This is useful when you want to use `WebDriver` methods without worrying about how that functionality is implemented.

Now casting it to `TakesScreenshot` means that whatever `driver` variable is, you are **hoping** that it also implements `TakesScreenshot`. Because if it does not, you will encounter a ClassCastException at runtime, as you observed.