# Map of Objects, can't access ArrayList element by index

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a `Map<String, Object>` in which I store `"test"` and `ArrayList<Integer>`. I then try to display  the whole array `testMap.get("test")` which works fine, but when I try to display not the whole array but rather its 1st element, it fails with `error: cannot find symbol:   method get(int)`.

```
public class Test  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> testMap = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> testArray = new ArrayList<>();
        testArray.add(1);
        testArray.add(2);
        testArray.add(3);

        testMap.put("test", testArray);

        //works fine, output: [1, 2, 3]
        System.out.println(testMap.get("test"));
        //get 1st element of testArray, error
        System.out.println(testMap.get("test").get(0));
    }
}
```

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

My guess was the type `Object` in the `Map` causes it, but I can't change it to `ArrayList` because the `Map` is supposed to store other types (like `String`, `Integer`) as well. So I tried:

```
System.out.println((ArrayList) testMap.get("test").get(0));
```

`System.out.println(((List<Integer>) testMap.get("test")).get(0))` didn't work too.

which still resulted in the error.

Comment: What do you mean by `System.out.println(((List<Integer>) testMap.get("test")).get(0)) didn't work too.`? Works fine for me (but ofc now you have an unchecked cast warning).

Comment: Btw using `Map<String, Object>` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: @m0skit0 valid point again, but it might be homework assignment, who knows...

Comment: @m0skit0 Don't know. `List` doesn't work, but `ArrayList` works. What's so wrong about wanting a dictionary that can store different types of values? If there is a better way to do it, I would gladly use it then. In python such dictionaries is a built-in function, why wouldn't one want to use them in java too?

Comment: @m0skit0 Figured out, the `List` wasn't imported, while the `ArrayList` was, that's why it didn't work.

Comment: Pro tip: Use an IDE, not a text editor, it will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Map holding a type of Object, you need to cast that result from Object to List.

```
 ArrayList<Integer> list =  (ArrayList<Integer>)testMap.get("test");
 System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

And it is bad practise to have Object as a value. Choose most specific type if possible.

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> testMap = new HashMap<>();
```

So that you can avoid casts. With the above declaration you can directly do

```
System.out.println(testMap.get("test").get(0));
```

If you have no option but have to use your map with Object type, instanceof is your friend. That helps you to have a check before doing any cast. So that you can avoid `ClassCastException`'s.

```
    Map<String, Object> testMap = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> testArray = new ArrayList<>();
    testArray.add(1);
    testArray.add(2);
    testArray.add(3);

    testMap.put("test", testArray);

    // works fine, output: [1, 2, 3]
    System.out.println(testMap.get("test"));
    // get 1st element of testArray, error
    if (testMap.get("test") instanceof ArrayList) {
        System.out.println(((ArrayList<Integer>) testMap.get("test")).get(0));
    }
```

Comment: **Incoming pedantry:** "Choose most specific type if possible" Choosing the most specific type is always possible

Comment: Please add the code how to check, before cast ;-) I mean `instanceof` check ;-)

Comment: @Michael I just don't want to sound like a commander :D

Comment: @Betlista ha ha. Good one.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ, But what to do if I need to have such a `Map` that can store different types for each key? Something like a `Python`'s dictionary? Is there a way to do it while avoiding bad practicing?

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ, not sure, but I was serious, not really joking...

Comment: @Ans Sure, I am going to update my answer. Although instaceof  works, I don't personally prefer.

Comment: @Betlista I see. Done now.

Comment: Good, I upvoted some time ago. @Ans this is the way how to distinguish specific types if you need to do so... As noted by several guys, it's not considered as a good practice.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend to define your map as

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> testMap = new HashMap<>();
```

if you are ok with ArrayLists to be values...

Comment: Or even better `Map<String, List<Integer>>`

Comment: Depends, but I kind of agree, more can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992384/program-to-an-interface-what-does-it-mean

Comment: How "depends", can you elaborate? The link you provided doesn't provide any argument on "depends" :)

Comment: @m0skit0 Your point is valid, but I wouldn't ovecomplicate it for a beginner, that's what I meant...

Comment: @Betlista If you think using the interface is over-complicating it, why are you using `Map`?

Comment: He's already using HashMap to Map, so I guess he already understands that ;)

Comment: I just think, OP copied the code from some tutorial... OP is not consistent, he used `Map... testMap`, but `ArrayList... testArray` instead of `List testArray`. I believe, just because someone is more experienced, do not need to criticize everythink, especially if the code is working. I like [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) idea. Also changing whole code might be scary - the relation inbetween original one and new might be lost (which I mean in general, not in this specific case).

Answer (score 3):

If you are storing mixed-type objects in the map, you circumvent Java's internal type checking system and have to make sure on your own that everything is ok.

For the compiler, `testMap.get("test")` is an `Object`. So you have to cast:

```
((ArrayList<Integer>)testMap.get("test")).get(0)
                     ^-----------------^   This is an Object
^---------------------------------------^  We have to cast this into an ArrayList.
```

Note the correct use of `()`s, as explained by the comments. Only then we can use its `.get()`.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS The explanation is directly below.

Comment: It is maybe clearer if you write something like `^--------------^ // Explanation for this line`, rather than what you have here.

Comment: @AndyTurner good idea, explanation can be next to code ;-)

Comment: @glglgl I've edited using my suggested syntax. Hopefully this is clearer; ofc, rollback if you don't like it.

Comment: @AndyTurner Very fine, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your `Map` to hold `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of `Object` type as shown below, otherwise, you need to go for the typecasting (which I don't recommend)

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> testMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Can't do this. It need to store other types too.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test  {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> testMap = new HashMap<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> testArray = new ArrayList<>();
            testArray.add(1);
            testArray.add(2);
            testArray.add(3);

            testMap.put("test", testArray);

            //works fine, output: [1, 2, 3]
            System.out.println(testMap.get("test"));
            //get 1st element of testArray, error

            System.out.println(testMap.get("test").get(0));
        }
    }
```

This will work

got the result

```
[1, 2, 3]
1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(((List<Integer>) testMap.get("test")).get(0));
```

Here you have casted your object to List which is an interface. You should use an Arraylist object to make this work.

```
System.out.println(((ArrayList<Integer>) testMap.get("test")).get(0));
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> testMap = new 
>    HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>();
> ```

Highlighted change alone is the only thing that you need. Making the generics as Object is always considered as Bad coding, because the output from that would be a Object and hence need typecasting  again.

> System.out.println(testMap.get("test").get(0));

Reason for the error is, Object method does not have a method of get() method. As i told you earlier, object is returned here.

So, going forward, make use of generics, which is a good coding practice and also they help you to resolve these errors in future.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> testArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    testArray.add(1);
    testArray.add(2);
    testArray.add(3);

    testMap.put("test", testArray);

    //works fine, output: [1, 2, 3]
    System.out.println(testMap.get("test"));
    //get 1st element of testArray, error
    System.out.println(testMap.get("test").get(0));
```