# Defining a 2D ArrayList with multiple ArrayLists inside

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>> newlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>>();
```

Above is my horrible `ArrayList` definition. I am trying to define an `ArrayList` containing multiple `ArrayList` inside although it gives me an `Incorrect number of arguments` error.

```
facilities = {
 [parking]
 [bike]
 [disability]
}
```

I am trying to make an `ArrayList` to hold this data above The main `ArrayList` (Facilities) will contain the inner `ArrayLists`. What is the correct way to define an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s?

Comment: You have multiple way to do it. Why would you need this? Why not use arrays?

Comment: @YassinHajaj can't create arrays of generic objects :/

Comment: @LonelyNeuron but these are strings right?

Comment: @YassinHajaj I meant `List<String>[]`

Comment: @LonelyNeuron You are right. I meant `String[][]` actually

Comment: @YassinHajaj well, then you have lost the advantage of a `List` :D

Answer (score 2):

First, [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) has only one type parameter, the type of all objects it contains, not each individual object.  Second, an `ArrayList` is not the correct choice for storing related data that should be in its own object.

Fixing just the first problem would result in you defining your `ArrayList` as:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
```

Additionally, usually you would [program to the interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992384/program-to-an-interface-what-does-it-mean) and define the variable as

```
List<List<String>>
```

You are free to use `ArrayList` or any other list as concrete implementations, of course, e.g.:

```
List<List<String>> newList = new ArrayList<>();
```

The second thing to fix would be to create a `Facility` class to encapsulate parking, bike, and disability.  Then your list to hold `Facility` objects becomes simply:

```
List<Facility> newList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You use:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array = new ArrayList<>();
array.add(//Your arrayList here);
```

You add `ArrayList`s to it just like you would `String`s to a regular `ArrayList` of `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Explanation please?

Comment: It declares ArrayList of ArrayLists of Strings :)

Comment: @Kermi it is a really poor answer if it doesn't explain the code. Don't just give people a solution, tell them **why** this is the solution.