# Is overriding toString() considered polymorphism?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding, late-binding, upcasting

I was having an exam in Java today and the examiner asked me if I can provide any examples of using polymorphism in my Spring Boot project.

As I couldn`t think of anything at first, he pointed out that I have overriden *toString()* in my models and that this is dynamic/runtime polymorphism.

However, I am not sure that I understand his point, because to my understanding, a behavior is considered polymorphmic when we have a **parent class reference variable pointing to a subclass object** (focusing on dynamic polymorphism).

Then at runtime the actual object, to which the parent class variable points to, is fetched and its method is called, as explained nicely [here](https://www.javaworld.com/article/3033445/java-101-polymorphism-in-java.html).

However, I do not use upcasting in my project (i.e. initializing my POJO classes with an Object class variable).

Thus, my question is - **is overriding toString() considered polymorphism, although the parent class (Object) is never used as a reference variable?**

All exampes of runtime polymorphism that I find on Stackoverflow, including the ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154673/11812518) one with toString, illustrate a situation where we have a parent class variable pointing to a subclass object, e.g:

```
    Object object = new User("petar");
    String name = object.toString(); // assign to variable for clarity`s sake
    System.out.println(name);
    // prints petar
```

Where my User class is:

```
public class User {

    String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

However, in my project I simply create users and other POJO classes with their own reference variables, e.g:

```
    User user = new User("petar");
    String name = user.toString();
    System.out.println(name);
    // prints petar, as toString is overriden
```

**Is the above considered polymorphism, although there is no upcasting / parent reference variable involved?**

My classmate argues that it is, because for *non-final instance methods*, the compiler doesn`t know which method to call - it only ensures that there is such method in the superclass, so it prolongs this decision up until runtime (*late binding*) by inserting an instruction into the compiled code, which is checked then and the actual object, to which the variable points to, is fetched, and its method is called ([source](https://www.javaworld.com/article/3033445/java-101-polymorphism-in-java.html)).

However, in [this article](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/method-overriding-in-java-with-example/) it is stated that:

> Method Overriding is an example of runtime polymorphism. When a **parent
>   class reference points to the child class object then the call to the
>   overridden method is determined at runtime**, because during method call
>   which method(parent class or child class) is to be executed is
>   determined by the type of object. This process in which call to the
>   overridden method is resolved at runtime is known as dynamic method
>   dispatch.

**So: is method overriding sufficient for polymorphism, or is it a requirement that there is a parent class reference to the subclass object? Am I safe to say at interviews that merely overriding toString() is an example of polymorphism?**

Comment: I’m inclined to agree with your classmate.  It is indeed polymorphism, since any program can treat a User instance as a general Object instance.

Comment: I'd say that having dynamic methods (calls) in itself is *part of* polymorphism, even if the object reference itself isn't cast to anything else. There is still a decision which method to call. To say that it is "polymorphism *in action*", well, I guess not. Things are never that black and white. Your professor was just trying to see if *you* get it, so pointing to a overridden method would indeed have been fine. Same in interviews really, they'll ask further in case you answer something like that (or they are crappy interviewers).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is polymorphism, what is it for, and how is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. @Maarten-reinstateMonica, thank you for your detailed explanation, I believe I get it now. There is always a decision which method to call for a non-final instance method, as the compiler never knows really - and from that viewpoint, one could indeed argue that this is polymorphism, although not "polymorphism in action" as you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments and a few other sources, I believe I can now answer my question as follows:

One could argue that **overriding toString()** **is** **an example of** **polymorphism** **because**:

The Java Virtual Machine (JVM) *always* selects the method to invoke on non-final *instance* methods based on the object that it is referenced to, and not the method defined by the variable type. This is known as dynamic method invocation or late binding i.e - the decision which method to call happens at runtime, hence the wording "runtime" polymorphism. Source: [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), [JavaWorld](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076949/how-the-java-virtual-machine-handles-method-invocation-and-return.html).

Thus, regardless whether we consciously use polymorphism by e.g. [programming to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1992412/11812518) or we do a simple toString() method override, but still continue to use our classes with their own class variables (i.e. using a "User" variable instead of the parent class "Object" variable), a **decision about which method to call is always made on runtime by checking the type of object our variables are referring to**.

Thus, the evaluation on which model to call (i.e. the polimorphic behavior) happens, regardless which of the two initializations we use:

```
    User user = new User("username1");
    System.out.println(user);
    
    // or

    Object object = new User("username1");
    System.out.println(object);
```

The *type* of the variable is insignificant for our question, what matters is the object that it is referring to, and which of all possible objects it refers to (i.e a parent or a child), is decided on runtime.

The *type* of the variable is only relevant to either limit the scope of available methods to the ones in the parent class and potentially overridden by its children (if we use a parent class reference variable) or to gain access to the specific methods of the child (if we use a child class reference variable).

For example, if we added a new method to our User class:

```
    public String instanceMethod () {
    return "User instance method called";
}
```

It would not be available through a Object class variable:

[image]

It would only be available through a User class variable.

Hope this clears the confusion for everyone else that needs a more detailed explanation too.