# How can I declare a new class but set its class "type" later?

Tags: java, class, if-statement, boolean

I'm working on a **Java** school project and I was wondering if I could instantiate a class but set its class type later on ?

I have two classes, *`Conference`* and *`ConferenceOnline`*. The latter is a subclass of *`Conference`*. Depending on a boolean, I want to create a new instance of *`ConferenceOnline`* if the boolean is true, else a new instance of *`Conference`*.

Here is an  example:

```java
boolean online = true;

if(online) {
  ConferenceOnline myclass = new ConferenceOnline();
}
else {
  Conference myclass = new Conference();
}

myclass.someMethod();
```

I could have instantiate the object before if/else but the fact that depending on *`online`* the object would not be created from the same class keeps me bugging.

I know it's not possible to create a variable inside an if statement and access it outside of the statement. Is there a way to do this except writing code inside the if else statement ?

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992384/program-to-an-interface-what-does-it-mean

Answer (score 2):

Since `ConferenceOnline` is a subclass of `Conference` (assuming `someMethod` is defined on `Conference`):

```
Conference myclass;
if (online) {
  myclass = new ConferenceOnline();
} else {
  myclass = new Conference();
}
myclass.someMethod();
```