# JPA. Specification, Implementation or both?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I study the JPA. The book uses classes, interfaces and annotations from javax.persistence package like @Entity,@Table,EntityManager etc to make a real and functional ORM application. When I searched to the Internet about JPA I read a few articles that said "JPA is just a specification, it doesn't perform any operation by itself. It requires an implementation (like Hibernate,TopLink etc)". And then what are all those classes in the javax.persistence??? Am I missing something?

Comment: They are the implementation provided by whatever framework or application server you're using.

Comment: There are very very few (POJO) classes in the API, 
 see here https://javadoc.io/doc/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api/latest/index.html . All this stuff is the specification poured in a contract, a bunch of interfaces, enums (constants) and errors (Exceptions). Then an implementor (like Hibernate) probably can add their things, but your code should go against the interfaces.

Comment: Didn't someone ask this exact question a day or two ago?

Answer (score 1):

## Specification

[*Jakarta Persistence*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/) is a specification published by the [Eclipse Foundation](https://www.eclipse.org/). (*Jakarta Persistence* was formerly known as *Java Persistence API (JPA)*, published  by [Oracle Corp.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation))

- [`@Entity`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/apidocs/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/entity) and [`@Table`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/apidocs/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/table) are [annotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation).
- [`EntityManager`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/apidocs/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/entitymanager) is an interface.

You said:

> And then what are all those classes in the javax.persistence???

Your premise is incorrect. These annotations and interfaces are not classes.

The annotations and interfaces defined in those specs are also written as Java source code files, published in [JAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) files by the Eclipse Foundation. But those Java files do not *do* anything; you need an implementation of those annotations and interfaces, [concrete classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)#Abstract_and_Concrete), to actually *do* something.

To be technically complete… The API of a specification such as *Jakarta Persistence* may contain some parts that are technically classes. For example, you may see enums and abstract classes. But their functionality is minimal. And these parts are useless without a complete implementation of the spec’s API. Conceptually, you should think of the spec’s API as having no classes.

## Implementation

Multiple implementations of the Jakarta Persistence [3.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/) and [3.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/) specs are available:

- [*EclipseLink*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EclipseLink) by Eclipse Foundation
- [*Hibernate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_(framework)) by Red Hat
- [*DataNucleus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DataNucleus)

You must **choose one of these implementations** in order to use the Jakarta Persistence [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API).

Alternatively, you can bypass the API of Jakarta Persistence, and instead directly access the API of one of those particular products. The product-specific API may be broader and more feature-rich than the Jakarta Persistence API.

The downside to using a product-specific API is that you are locking your code into that one particular product & vendor. By going through the Jakarta Persistence you may be able to switch between implementations with little or no difficulty.

You said:

> a few articles that said "JPA is just a specification, it doesn't perform any operation by itself. It requires an implementation (like Hibernate,TopLink etc)".

Those articles are correct. The interfaces defined by the specification must be backed by an implementation at runtime.

- If you are using a Jakarta EE compliant application server such as Glassfish, Payara, OpenLiberty, WildFly, etc., both the specification’s API and the implementation will be provided by that server product. So you do *not* bundle either in your WAR/EAR.
- If you are developing a console app or desktop/mobile app, you bundle both the specification’s API and an implementation of your choice.

Maven’s POM’s `scope` element controls whether the API and/or implementation JARs get bundled. Gradle has a similar feature.

By the way, [*TopLink*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_TopLink) was donated by Oracle to the Eclipse Foundation where it became *EclipseLink*.

---

By the way, as of the transition from Java EE to Jakarta EE, the use of abbreviations like *JPA* is now discouraged. The full name of each technology is preferred.

Comment: *"... the use of abbreviations like JPA is now discouraged."* - IMO, Oracle's lawyers are "on a hiding to nothing" if they want to stop people using JPA.  (Like Xerox's lawyers were ...)

Comment: @StephenC As I recall hearing from people involved in Jakarta EE, their reason to avoid such abbreviations was not legal concerns, nor any request by Oracle. Their motivation is that they fear all the "J…" abbreviations flying around is confusing to people new to the techonolgiies. They hope to make Jakarta EE more broadly accessible. Simplifying, and then using, the full names is one of their strategies towards that goal. I whole-heartedly agree with them.

Comment: I didn't understand anything. I need to put them in order. So based on "If you are using a Jakarta EE compliant application server..." I use TomEE. Then I searched where .jar file javax.persistence package came from. And I found a file "eclipselink-2.7.7.jar" under the Server Runtime library (TomEE) that my example uses. So the book uses this implementation by referring to it misleadingly as JPA and you get the impression that JPA is a normal library.

Comment: @nonlinear Do you understand what it means to [program to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1992384/642706)? It is crucial that you understand that concept.

Comment: (A) If one wants to develop  a console app or a desktop/mobile app that uses the Jakarta Persistence API, one must bundle with that app both the Jakarta Persistence API JAR file *and* an implementation JAR file such as EclipseLink or Hibernate. (B) In a web app on a Jakarta-compliant application server, the server comes with both the Jakarta Persistence API and an implementation. So you need both the Jakarta Persistence API and an implementation in your project during development but would *not* bundle into your final WAR/EAR file. Maven `scope` element controls whether those JARs get bundled.

Comment: "Jakarta Persistence API JAR file". Where is this file in tomee? It contains only the interfaces? If I use Tomcat with a maven project then I need to add a dependency to get the function of persistence?

Comment: @nonlinear See [the documentation](https://tomee.apache.org/tomee-9.0/docs/comparison.html#implementations) for a list of Jakarta APIs supported by TomEE, along with a list of the implementations they utilize. How the makers of TomEE choose to package their app server product is irrelevant. All we care about is that the current version of TomEE supports *Jakarta Persistence (JPA) 3.0* in all editions. So your web app can rely on those APIs being available at runtime. P.S. Don't confuse Tomcat for TomEE. TomEE is a superset of Tomcat, adding on many more of the Jakarta EE technologies.

Comment: "All we care about is that the current version of TomEE supports Jakarta Persistence (JPA) 3.0 in all editions.". No. Not me. That's not enough for me. I care to know which of these files are specification related and which are implementation related. Do I have to read all this to answer such a question?

Comment: And I haven't gotten an answer about the nature of the files related to the specifications. Since they are specifications I reasonably assume they will be interfaces. And also since the specification is a standard it should be a common shared .jar of interfaces that must be implemented from various providers.

Comment: @nonlinear Fortunately for your curiosity, TomEE is open-source. So you can dig around to see how it gets packaged. Happy spelunking.