# How do I select a class dynamically?

Tags: java, class, dynamic

I have two classes that extends a third class, i.e.

```
public class class_a extends parent_class
```

and

```
public class class_b extends parent_class
```

My question is it possible to have a third class to create a reference to a class based on condition? i.e.

```
public void test() {
  parent_class b;
  if (cond)
    b = new class_a();
  else
    b = new class_b();
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

I don't want to create variables per type of class, I will only use one throughout the life time of this function.

Comment: Have you tried running the code? It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is exactly what the factory design pattern is for.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

This might also be of use [Factory Pattern. When to use factory methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69849/factory-pattern-when-to-use-factory-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
[Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) allows you threat subclass as base class.
So, you can write method with parent_class return value type, like so:

```
parent_class create(boolean condition)
{
   return condition ? new class_a() : new class_b();      
}
```

As @John answered, it is called Factory method.

P.S. In Java, you better should name classes using [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), like ClassA and ParentClass. [Code style.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: Thank you, I will take your comment regarding the CamelCase as well.