# C# How to make a factory method return of the subclass type

Tags: c#

[MAJOR EDITS, my first post was somewhat misleading. My appologies]

Given a class such as:

```
public class DatabaseResult{
    public bool Successful;
    public string ErrorMessage;     

    //Database operation failed
    public static DatabaseResult Failed(string message) {
         return new DatabaseResult{
             Successful = true,
             ErrorMessage = message
         };
    }
}
```

How can I implement subclasses such that I can add additional properties to represent data relevant to the particular operation (such as MatchedResult in the case of a SELECT type query) without the need to implement that static failure function?  If I try to use plain inheritance, the return type will be of the parent class.  Eg:

```
DoThingDatabaseResult : DatabaseResult {
     public IEnumerable<object> SomeResultSet;
     public static Successful(IEnumerable<object> theResults){
          return new DoThingDatabaseResult {
               Successful = true,
               ErrorMessage = "",
               SomeResultSet = theResults
          };
     }
     //public static DatabaseResult Failed exists, but it's the parent type!
}
```

The goal is to avoid needing to copy the Failed static function for every subclass implementation.

Comment: Wow! So many responses. Looking them over now.

Comment: I think the main problem here is that we don't really understand what you would like to actually accomplish. Do you want to call the `SomeFactoryMethod` on any arbitrary descendant of `BankAccount`, and have it return an object typed as that descendant, instead of `BankAccount`, or do you need something else?

Comment: The clarification at the bottom is a bit contrary to the rest of the question. How do you plan on mapping the values you get from the database to the right type?

Comment: I think I'm going to make a large edit. Just a moment.  I think actual examples may prove useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it recursively generic:

```
public class BankAccount<T> where T : BankAccount<T>, new()
{
    public T SomeFactoryMethod() { return new T(); }
}

public class SavingsAccount: BankAccount<SavingsAccount>{}
```

You'll note that I made the factory method non-static, because static methods aren't inherited.

Comment: There's no reason to use generics here, simply removing static from his methods and adding virtual/override would do.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this doesn't seem particularly useful. You'd need an instance of the class in order to create an instance of the class. This would be great if the question were asking for it to perform some conversion on the members (like, say, a strongly-typed clone). But it doesn't make much sense for a factory class to require an instance of itself to create anything.

Comment: Agreed with @MatthewHaugen - it's clever, but I'm not sure how this would be useful.

Comment: If you make the `SomeFactoryMethod` static, it should do the trick.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen if it were that easy, yeah. But then you wouldn't be able to inherit it, which I believe is what the goal was. By making it static, you're basically just providing a wrapper for the constructor. That's useful for some cases, but it's not what the question was asking for.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen No, @MatthewHaugen is right. Remember, there is no inheritance of static methods. So the only way of calling would be `BankAccount<SavingsAccount>.SomeFactoryMethod()`.

Comment: I updated the post with thoughts from this answer. It's very close to what I'm looking for, but as commented above, it's not very useful without the static keyword.  Aside from that, it's just what I'm looking for. Basically, I'm trying to avoid having to type overrides or other boilerplate on each new subclass. This is the DRYest answer so far, which is what I'm going for.

Comment: You can call `SavingsAccount.SomeFactoryMethod`, it will return an object of type `SavingsAccount`. I'm well aware that inheritance and static are orthogonal. I assumed "inheritance" here meant something other than the normal usage of the word, since you don't actually "inherit" static methods per se.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I respect that, certainly. I just figured he wanted to do something different in each inheriting class (like, if there was something special about `SavingsAccount` that needed some particular action taken when it was created that would suit the factory flow best). I think the desire for static inheritance is fairly reasonable, it just isn't something that the language supports right now. I guess in other words, I'm not disputing that your answer is probably the best there is (if you made it static), I'm just saying it doesn't sound like what the OP was looking for is possible.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow. If you declare another account class, inheriting from `BankAccount<T>`, where `T` is the type of the inheriting class, and then implement a new `SomeFactoryMethod` method there, then `SavingsAccount.SomeFactoryMethod()` and `SomeOtherAccount.SomeFactoryMethod()` will in fact call the right methods. I think the main problem here might be our understanding of the question, not what the language allows for.

Comment: I've awarded this answer as it properly answers my question as stated. I do realize however that I've written this poorly so I'll be making a new one that's a bit more polished later this evening with some concrete examples.  Thank you all for your help. I am quite floored with the volume of the responses I got.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this exactly as you have defined the question. The best way to tackle this is really to pull your factory out of the class completely:

```
public class BankAccount
{
}

public class SavingsAccount : BankAccount
{
}

public static class BankAccountFactory
{
    public static T Create<T>() where T : BankAccount, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Now the Factory has no dependency on the actual type. You can pass any derived class of BankAccount and get it back without doing any extra work or worrying about inheriting your factory method.

Comment: If you need the type when you generate the class, how is this different than using the constructor directly?

Comment: @KyleW that's getting into a discussion of what the Factory Pattern is and why it's useful. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69849/factory-pattern-when-to-use-factory-methods and http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html for starters.

Comment: I suppose that's true.  I wasn't thinking about resolving dependencies.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to avoid the need to explicitly re-type these factory methods, as aside from the type, the same operation should occur.

Comment: @OliverKane there is no duplication. You just need **one** factory. Forget about the static methods, use the factory directly.

Comment: @rsenna, To avoid the class noise, would it be possible to just do this?

public class BankAccount {
        public static T Create<T>() where T : BankAccount, new() {
            return new T();
        }
    }

Comment: Tim, looking this over, I realize that I've written this question quite poorly. As written, Matthew's got the correct answer so I'm going to award it to him. Either later today or tomorrow, I'll write up one that's more what I was asking and you'll be welcome to post this there. I'll be happy to award you as well as this post solved the real world issue.

Comment: What does this answer provide other than a roundabout way to say `new SomeAccountType()` ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I'm slow getting back to this, but that goes back again to what the factory method is. See the link above - the whole purpose of the factory pattern is to get around explicitly creating a new instance of a type. Your concern is a question of how the factory pattern works in general, not really about this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I may, I'd like to expand upon StriplingWarrior.  In fact, you can use static for the factory.  This following code shows that a and c are the expected object types.  The limit is you cannot use the factory on the base class itself.

```
 private void Testit()
    {
        var a = SavingsAccount.Factory();
        var c = CheckingAccount.Factory();
        //var b = BankAccount.Factory(); //can't do this
    }


public class BankAccount<T> where T : BankAccount<T>, new()
{
    public static T Factory()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}

public class SavingsAccount : BankAccount<SavingsAccount>
{
}

public class CheckingAccount : BankAccount<CheckingAccount>
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use inheritance, you need an instance of an object and a member of that object.  In this case, for the object we can't use `BankAccount/SavingsAccount` because then we would already have what we're trying to get.  This means we need an actual factory object, which is what most people are talking about when they talk about a factory.  So if we pull that out into a Factory and use inheritance...

```
public class BankAccountFactory { public virtual GetAccount() { return new BankAccount(); } }
public class SavingsAccountFactory : BankAccountFactory { public override GetAccount() { return new SavingsAccount(); } }
```

But now how do we get an instance of the proper type?  We've just pushed our problem one layer deeper.

Instead, what you probably want to do, is use some sort of configuration to determine the type, or pass the type you want into a method.

```
public BankAccount GetAccount(AccountType type) { /* */ }
```

or

```
public BankAccount GetAccount() { /* Access config */ }
```

For a simple answer to your question: You don't need to use generics or anything like that, you just need your method to not be static...