# Typescript Type Declaration for Abstract Class Implementations

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out how to provide a type definition that corresponds to "all classes that implement some abstract class." Take the following code example:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo {
  abstract foo()
}

class Concrete1 extends AbstractFoo {
  foo() { ... }
}

class Concrete1 extends AbstractFoo {
  foo() { ... }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to create a map that goes from `string` to one of the concrete classes. Note that I am *not* trying to map into instances of the concrete classes. See the following:

```
const myMap: Map<string, typeINeedHelpWith> = new Map()
myMap.set('concrete1string', Concrete1)
myMap.set('concrete2string', Concrete2)

const instantiatedConcrete1 = new myMap.get('concrete1string')(...)
```

Is there a type definition for `typeINeedHelpWith` that would let me accomplish this?

Comment: It will be `const myMap: Map<string, new () => AbstractFoo>`, then `const instantiatedConcrete1 = new (myMap.get('concrete1string'))!()`

Answer (score 2):

Use a function that returns the concrete instance as map value.

**Update**: The below suggestion is just valid for [deno](https://deno.land/)

As a suggestion, it is better to use a [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) type instead of a `Map` because otherwise wrong keys
(`mymap.get("concrete3")()`) will be noticed as runtime exceptions.

```
abstract class AbstractFoo {
    abstract foo(): number;
  }

  class Concrete1 extends AbstractFoo {
    foo() {
      return 1;
    }
  }

  class Concrete2 extends AbstractFoo {
    foo() {
      return 2;
    }
  }

  const myMap: Record<string, () => AbstractFoo> = {
    "concrete1": () => new Concrete1(),
    "concrete2": () => new Concrete2(),
  };

  const instantiatedConcrete1 = myMap.concrete1();

  let fooResult = instantiatedConcrete1.foo();
```

As noted in the comments, notice that I've used a [factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69849/factory-pattern-when-to-use-factory-methods) for creating objects.

This is recognized as a good design pattern, but when not required a simpler constructor based solution may be more appropriate:

```
const myRec: Record<string, new() => AbstractFoo> = {
  "concrete1": Concrete1,
  "concrete2": Concrete2,
};

const iConcrete1 = new myRec.concrete1();
```

The sintax `new() => AbstractFoo` define the signature of a constructor that takes no arguments and returns object with shape `AbstractFoo`.

Comment: No need to wrap in factory function. Just `const myMap: Record<string, new () => AbstractFoo> = { "concrete1": Concrete1, "concrete2": Concrete2 };`, then `const instantiatedConcrete1 = new myMap.concrete1();`

Comment: Also "object map" (`Record<...>`) has exactly the same problem with wrong keys: `myMap.concrete3();`...

Comment: My wrong, I've verified my answer only with deno, Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the only type available is `typeof AbstractFoo`, that is the constructor type. Like `typeof Array` refers to the type of the `Array` constructor, while the type `Array` refers to the type of array instances.

Both `Concrete1` and `Concrete2` extend that type (more precisely `typeof Concrete1` and `typeof Concrete2` extend `typeof AbstractFoo`)

But you can't create a map like the following:

```js
const myMap: Map<string, typeof AbstractFoo> = new Map()
myMap.set('concrete1string', Concrete1)
myMap.set('concrete2string', Concrete2)
```

Nay, you can, but the return type of `myMap.get('concrete1string')` is `typeof AbstractFoo`, not `typeof Concrete1`. You cannot call, with `new`, a constructor of type `typeof AbstractFoo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, using mapped types:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo {
    abstract foo(): string;
}

class Concrete1 extends AbstractFoo {
  foo() { return "Concrete 1" }
}

class Concrete2 extends AbstractFoo {
  foo() { return "Concrete 2" }
}

interface Mapping {
    'concrete1string': Concrete1,
    'concrete2string': Concrete2
}

class MyHeplerMap {
    maps: Mapping = {
        'concrete1string': new Concrete1(),
        'concrete2string': new Concrete2()
    };

    get<T extends keyof Mapping>(type: T): Mapping[T] {
        return this.maps[type];
    }
}

const map = new MyHeplerMap();
const c = map.get('concrete1string');
console.log(c.foo());
```

Please see playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=23&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=7#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgguacIDEB7QhAbwCgEqFRIZ4EAzYgCgEoAuBOgSwDsA5gG5yAX3LkUaDAGFCfWFACmEJQEYESgB6q+AEwzY6eIiQpVmhdmQTKIAVyh8EAIjkK7ShGpcJx4yVR0BHdFFSUAJk0dJX1DHHoCYjJKJlY2GztHZzd5MNUECN9-CX5VKEY4LwBZYAAHOv4BFOoEAHJYPM81XkE2rlDugBpUqg6u8IjegX6QidUIsQkpYOqATwAJJTrkJShaupbqAFt6sC4DxsEEAF4j1rHOj3Ce6CbZviUAdznn1TV2CMHtRxn9ItMPt9fvlIuxRn4RPCBCoADwAFWiugMCAA1ko1oRGAhLk0AHwsCBrOpKLhozjE+pXAQAbTRAF17g8sk4EBAABY8MAAOlOdTAzMp1LZIlaJUk8kgCFFtwQnx+6y2Oz2B3YIieitgKtFQuREBYoJhryg7zYeoVhF2QuQhAELFgQss7FtQA).